# Android MediaPlayer setDataSource failed with file names containing letter '#'

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

I am creating MediaPlayer instance using

```
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/soundrecorder/" + arrPackage.get(0)));
```

This code gives error when filename contain the letter '#'. For example:

```
file path: /storage/emulated/0/soundrecorder/My Recording #1.wav
```

but works fine for

```
file path: /storage/emulated/0/soundrecorder/My Recording 1.wav
```

I have tried searching but could not find the answer.

```
04-29 19:54:13.829 31618-31618/com.audiorecorder.wel.voicerecorder D/MediaPlayer: create failed:
                                                                              java.io.IOException: setDataSource failed.
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1212)
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1140)
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1074)
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1055)
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:923)
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:900)
                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:879)
```

It gives this error on Android 4.4.2 and Android 5.0.2 but works fine on Android 7.1.1.

Can some one tell me what could possibly be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/soundrecorder/" + arrPackage.get(0))
```

with:

```
Uri.fromFile(new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "soundrecorder"), arrPackage.get(0))
```

and see if you have better luck. You are not using a valid `Uri` in your existing code (no scheme), and the `#` may be mis-handled as a result (URL-style encoding).